# UITextField Alignment issue iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield

I am stuck in a very strange problem. A default text field in iOS 8 & 7 behave very strange.
If the text box got focused the alignment of text get changed check the screen shots.

even with very small text size

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginForm : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_username;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txt_password;
- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Maybe you are changing the text alignment in your code. Do you have any UITextFieldDelegate methods? If yes, please show us your code.

Comment: I am not using any. And check the header file there is nothing

Comment: Try this then. Its more of a work around, not exactly getting to the root of the problem but set your VC as a UITextFieldDelegate, then make it the textFields delegate and use the following code. - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Its more of a work around, not exactly getting to the root of the problem but make your VC a UITextFieldDelegate, then make it the textFields delegate and use the following code. -

```
(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Change the alignment if you need to.
    textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}
```

Comment: by deleting all text fields and creating again solved the problem. You solution also will work i think but did't try.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a alignment issue. In your storyboard check the UITextField Alignment matches with the below image.

[image]

Comment: it's exactly same and this is happening in the whole app.